# How to check color of the image using python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, selenium-webdriver

I have 3 images. red, green, black.

I want to check color of the image. I tried doing with below code. But I am getting error. How can I check color of the image?

```
    im = Image.open(im3_B)    
    im.load()                
    ColorOfImage= list(set(im.getdata()))
    if all(rgb == (0,0,0) for rgb in im.getdata()):
    print (" black")
```

( Images like : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=green+color&biw=1440&bih=775&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil_KmdoJzLAhXHSY4KHebuBfkQ_AUIBygB#imgrc=4DFvEP_p8LmBcM%3A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use matplotlib to read pixel values. Assuming you are looking for the color black:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = plt.imread('/user/some/path.jpg')


for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for k in range(image.shape[1]):
        if image[i,k,0] == 0 and image[i,k,1] == 0 and image[i,k,2] == 0:  #0 is R, 1 is G, 2 is B, i and k is each rown and column of pixels.
            print("Pixel [%d|%d] is black % (i, k))
```